# GWT - passing Java arrays to Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni, gwt-exporter

I am a newcomer to GWT and Javascript.

I am trying to send in a java int[] to my javascript function. I am using a gwt-exporter to handle the processing for me. This is how I have set things up.

```java
static class gwtExplorerTest implements Exportable {

    @Export("$wnd.handleAnchorClick")
    public static void handleAnchorClick(int param1, int param2 , int[] a1 , int[] a2)
    {
        //process  things here          
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with javascript code to pass in the arrays I need here? What I currently have is:

```
href="javascript:window.handleAnchorClick(" + currentRow + "," + currentColumn + "," + rowVals + "," + colVals + ",") "
```

as my JS function call, where rowVals and colVals are the two arrays I need to pass in. It does not seem to work. Can someone please help me out?

Thanks

Comment: As I can deduce from your code, what you are trying is to pass arrays from your javascript to your java function. aren't you? if so take a look to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function in java is right and gwt-exporter supports this syntax. The call from JS should be like:

```
 window.handleAnchorClick(1, 2, [3,4], [5,6])
```

Your problem is that you are trying to call the exported method from a `href` attribute in your `html` and you are using a bad syntax.

First, it is better to use the `onClick` attribute instead of `href`, because you dont need the `javascript:` tag, and it is better to prevent default. And, I'd rather define a function to do the call to avoid syntax issues.

```html
<script>
  var currentRow = 1;
  var currentColumn = 2;
  var rowVals = [3,4];
  var colVals = [5,6];

  function mycall() {
    window.handleAnchorClick(currentRow, currentColumn, rowVals, colVals);
  }
</script>

<!-- I prefer this -->
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:mycall()">click</a>

<!-- But this should work as well -->
<a href="#" onClick="window.handleAnchorClick(currentRow,currentColumn,rowVals,colVals)">click</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. And sorry for the late reply!.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using json string, then i hope you need to change parameter type to string in handleAnchorClick method. Then you need to typecast to json.